# Showing data after being submitted with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to display data after being submitted with ajax. The ajax works so far when submitting, but I have to refresh to see it.

Here's the jquery:

```
$('#submit-quote').live("submit", function(){
    var formdata = $(this).serialize();
    $.post("add.php", formdata, function(data) {
        console.log("success"); 
    });
    return false;
});
```

The php in add.php:

```
require('includes/connect.php');

$quote = $_POST['quote'];
$quotes = mysql_real_escape_string($quote);

echo $quotes . "Added to database";

mysql_query("INSERT INTO entries (quote) VALUES('$quotes')")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Here's the HTML/PHP that I use to fetch the data and display it:

```
<?php 
    require("includes/connect.php");

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM entries", $link);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
        <div class="quote-wrap group">
            <span>Like</span>
            <div class="quote">
                <p>
                <?php echo htmlentities($row['quote']); ?>
                </p>
            </div><!-- /.quote -->
        </div><!-- /.quote-wrap -->

 <?php } ?>
```

If needed, here's the form:

```
<form id="submit-quote" method="post" >
     <h2> Submit A Quote </h2>
     <textarea name="quote">
     </textarea>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

Ajax works when submitting, but I need to display it after being sent also, how can I do this?

Comment: What do you want to display, your success message or the data that was submitted to the database?

Comment: Just so you know, `live` has been deprecated in jQuery 1.7.1.  You should use `on` instead.  http://api.jquery.com/on/  Older versions of jQuery should use `delegate` instead of `live`.

Comment: It looks to me like you're open to SQL injection by just inserting $quote, unless i'm wrong and that's not just string interpolation. Be careful!

Comment: Thanks david and john, I'm just a beginner so I don't really know :/ Just starting to get this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` variable in your `success` callback function stores the server response. So to add the server response to the DOM:

```
$(document).delegate("'#submit-quote'", "submit", function(){
    $.post("add.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        $('.inner').append('<div class="quote-wrap group"><span>Like</span><div class="quote"><p>' + data + '</p></div></div>');
    });
    return false;
});
```

If you need to use event delegate (e.g. the form isn't always present in the DOM) then use `.delegate()` instead of `.live()` as the latter has been depreciated as of jQuery 1.7.

Also you don't really need to cache `$(this).serialize()` in a variable since it is only being used once (creating the variable is unnecessary overhead).

Since your PHP code is outputting `echo $quotes . "Added to database";`, the server response will be the quote with "Added to database` appended to the string, which will be added to your list of quotes.

**UPDATE**

```
$(document).delegate("'#submit-quote'", "submit", function(){
    var quoteVal = $(this).find('[name="quote"]').val();
    $.post("add.php", $(this).serialize(), function() {
        $('.inner').append('<div class="quote-wrap group"><span>Like</span><div class="quote"><p>' + quoteVal+ '</p></div></div>');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Notice that I am no longer referencing the server response (in fact I removed the `data` variable all together). Instead I am saving the value of the `name="quote"` element within the form being submitted and using it after the AJAX request comes back (this way the quote is added to the database before being added to the DOM). You could move the `.append()` code outside the `success` callback to run it right as the form is submitted (in the `submit` event handler).

**UPDATE**

If you want to create a DOM element to append rather than concocting a string:

```
$(document).delegate("'#submit-quote'", "submit", function(){
    var quoteVal = $(this).find('[name="quote"]').val();
    $.post("add.php", $(this).serialize(), function() {

        //create parent div and add classes to it
        $('<div />').addClass('quote-wrap group').append(

            //append the "like" span to the parent div
            $('<span />').text('Like');
        ).append(

            //also append the .quote div to the parent div
            $('<div />').addClass('quote').append(

                //then finally append the paragraph tag with the quote text to the .quote div
                $('<p />').text(quoteVal)
            )

        //then after we're done making our DOM elements, we append them all to the .inner element
        ).appendTo('.inner');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This only returns what's echoed in add.php which is echo $quotes . "Added to database"; .. i tried $('.inner').html(data) but that removes all html from the parent and inserts whats echoed in add.php (.inner being the parent for the html the data is being displayed in)

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant to use `.append()` instead of `.html()`. The former will add itself to the end of the `.inner` element (or if you want to add it to the beginning use `.prepend()`. `.html(<some-html>)` is the same as `.empty().append(<some-html>)`. My answer is updated.

Comment: I copied and pasted in your code but it doesn't work. Refreshes page and nothing is submitted

Comment: @Trippy There was an error at the end of the `.append()` call, there was a reference to the `data` variable that was not be concocted properly. Try the code again. More importantly you should be watching an error console to spot these types of errors quickly (instead of stumbling across the errors randomly).

Comment: Thank you. It's "kinda" working now. It submits but where it's submitted to is empty. After refreshing the page it shows the content.

Comment: After the `success` callback function runs, use your developer tools to inspect the `.inner` element to see if the server response has been properly added to the DOM. I don't really know what your HTML looks like so I can't get too much more precise.

Comment: It's placing empty <div class="quote"><p></p></div> without content in <p>

Comment: That means that nothing is being returned from the server. The server response is just whatever is output on the server-side script. If you `echo "foobar"` in your PHP script, the JavaScript AJAX request will get `foobar` as the response (in this case the `data` JS variable will have the value of `foobar`).

Comment: Your AJAX request is making a HTTP request to your PHP script (`add.php`), your PHP script is then run, once your PHP script finishes running it is output back to the AJAX function (the `success` callback), and finally the AJAX function is passed the output from the PHP script (or whatever page you requested). If you request a regular HTML document in your AJAX call, you will be returned the whole HTML document, starting with `<!doctype...`.

Comment: How can I return the data that was submitted though? It's almost working.

Comment: After you add the new database row, `echo $_GET['quote']`. Although if this is the only information you want to update in the DOM then you might as well just use the value you got before submitting the AJAX request. See my answer for an update regarding this idea.

Comment: Perfect. It works great. Thank you! I have one question though if you mind if you can answer (I already choosed you as the best answer). I dislike having the HTML in .append(). Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: @Trippy Check the latest update to the question. It creates DOM elements that are appended to the DOM without concocting strings.